# ReferenceError: describe is not defined,

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

the problem i am having is i cant debug my code in visual studio code i keep getting the error 'ReferenceError: describe is not defined' i cant find a viable solution for it to work any help would be amazing.

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Program",
  "skipFiles": [
    "<node_internals>/**"
  ],
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/koans/AboutApplyingWhatWeHaveLearnt.js"
}]}
```

---

enter code here /Users/sambrandon/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin/node ./koans/AboutApplyingWhatWeHaveLearnt.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49497/462da266-3a0b-453c-8130-d64c67860648
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
/Users/sambrandon/Desktop/Koon/seip2010-javascript-koans/koans/AboutApplyingWhatWeHaveLearnt.js:4
describe('About Applying What We Have Learnt', function() {
^

ReferenceError: describe is not defined
at Object. (/Users/sambrandon/Desktop/Koon/seip2010-javascript-koans/koans/AboutApplyingWhatWeHaveLearnt.js:4:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
Process exited with code 1

```js
var _; // globals


describe('About Applying What We Have Learnt', function() {
  var products;

  beforeEach(function () {
    products = [
      { name: 'Sonoma', ingredients: ['artichoke', 'sundried tomatoes', 'mushrooms'], containsNuts: false },
      { name: 'Pizza Primavera', ingredients: ['roma', 'sundried tomatoes', 'goats cheese', 'rosemary'], containsNuts: false },
      { name: 'South Of The Border', ingredients: ['black beans', 'jalapenos', 'mushrooms'], containsNuts: false },
      { name: 'Blue Moon', ingredients: ['blue cheese', 'garlic', 'walnuts'], containsNuts: true },
      { name: 'Taste Of Athens', ingredients: ['spinach', 'kalamata olives', 'sesame seeds'], containsNuts: true }
    ];
  });

  /*********************************************************************************/

  it('given I\'m allergic to nuts and hate mushrooms, it should find a pizza I can eat (imperative)', function () {
    var i, j, hasMushrooms;
    var productsICanEat = [];

    for (i = 0; i < products.length; i += 1) {
      if (products[i].containsNuts === false) {
        hasMushrooms = false;
        for (j = 0; j < products[i].ingredients.length; j += 1) {
          if (products[i].ingredients[j] === 'mushrooms') {
            hasMushrooms = true;
          }
        }
        if (!hasMushrooms) {
          productsICanEat.push(products[i]);
        }
      }
    }

    expect(productsICanEat.length).toBe(1);
  });

  it('given I\'m allergic to nuts and hate mushrooms, it should find a pizza I can eat (functional)', function () {
    var productsICanEat = [];


    /* solve using filter() & all() / any() */

    // var pizzas = _(products.name).filter(function(x) {
    //   return _(products.name[x]).any('pizza');
    // });
    console.log(pizzas);


    expect(productsICanEat.length).toBe(0);
  });

  /*********************************************************************************/

  it('should add all the natural numbers below 1000 that are multiples of 3 or 5 (imperative)', function () {
    var sum = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i += 1) {
      if (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) {
        sum += i;
      }
    }

    expect(sum).toBe(FILL_ME_IN);
  });

  it('should add all the natural numbers below 1000 that are multiples of 3 or 5 (functional)', function () {
    var sum = FILL_ME_IN; /* try chaining range() and reduce() */

    expect(233168).toBe(FILL_ME_IN);
  });

  /*********************************************************************************/
  it('should count the ingredient occurrence (imperative)', function () {
    var ingredientCount = { '{ingredient name}': 0 };

    for (i = 0; i < products.length; i += 1) {
      for (j = 0; j < products[i].ingredients.length; j += 1) {
        ingredientCount[products[i].ingredients[j]] = (ingredientCount[products[i].ingredients[j]] || 0) + 1;
      }
    }

    expect(ingredientCount['mushrooms']).toBe(FILL_ME_IN);
  });

  it('should count the ingredient occurrence (functional)', function () {
    var ingredientCount = { '{ingredient name}': 0 };

    /* chain() together map(), flatten() and reduce() */

    expect(ingredientCount['mushrooms']).toBe(FILL_ME_IN);
  });

  /*********************************************************************************/
  /* UNCOMMENT FOR EXTRA CREDIT */
  /*
  it('should find the largest prime factor of a composite number', function () {

  });

  it('should find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3 digit numbers', function () {

  });

  it('should find the smallest number divisible by each of the numbers 1 to 20', function () {


  });

  it('should find the difference between the sum of the squares and the square of the sums', function () {

  });

  it('should find the 10001st prime', function () {

  });
  */
});
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `Users/sambrandon/Desktop/Koon/seip2010-javascript-koans/koans/AboutApplyingWhatWeHaveLearnt.js`

Comment: There might be a test starting with describe in the main file. And  I guess you haven't installed the dependencies to make describe recognized

Comment: you have to `import` the test framework, look at an example in the doc of the framework